# self-polar spherical triangles

Tags: spherical-geometry

I want to show that in $S^2$ all self-polar triangles are congruent.

I know that if a triangle has angles $A,B,C$ and opposite sides $a,b,c$, then for its polar triangle we have :

$A'=π-a$, $Β'=π-b$, $C'=π-c$

and for its sides

$a'=π-A$, $b'=π-B$, $c'=π-C$

My intuition is that in order a triangle to be self polar it has to be

$A=B=C=π/2 $

and

$a=b=c=π/2$

(from the definition of a polar triangle)

However if we consider a triangle such that $a=π-A$ , $b=π-B$ , $c=π-C$ then this triangle has to be self-polar, since it fullfils the equalities above.

Hence, why a spherical triangle with angles $A=π/2$, $B=2π/3$, $C=π/4$

and sides $a=π/2$, $b=π/3$, $c=3π/4$

is not a self-polar triangle?

Thanks in advance for your time.